# btrfs mount options problem

Tags: mount, btrfs

I have Ubuntu 19.04 with 2 btrfs filesystems on hdd and ssd: /dev/sda3, /dev/nvme0n1p2.

I want to disable COW (option "nodatacow") on the subvolumes "vm" and "downloads" of sda3, and contrary enable COW and compression on other volumes.

But this don't work nether manual mount:

```
$ sudo mount -o subvol=@,datacow,compress /dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3
```

nor via my /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=eb879365-68a7-472f-8881-d5bf913da8bc   /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@,compress,ssd 0       1    
UUID=eb879365-68a7-472f-8881-d5bf913da8bc   /boot           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@boot,compress,ssd 0       1
UUID=3288-160B                              /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1    
UUID=eb879365-68a7-472f-8881-d5bf913da8bc   /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home,compress,ssd 0       2

UUID=a54e1e49-20d2-4ab5-a831-692d339a1112 /mnt/downloads  btrfs   defaults,noatime,nodatacow,subvol=@downloads 0       2
UUID=a54e1e49-20d2-4ab5-a831-692d339a1112 /mnt/vm         btrfs   defaults,noatime,nodatacow,subvol=@vm 0       2    
UUID=a54e1e49-20d2-4ab5-a831-692d339a1112 /mnt/sda3               btrfs   defaults,space_cache,compress,subvol=@ 0       1
UUID=a54e1e49-20d2-4ab5-a831-692d339a1112 /mnt/sda3_home          btrfs   defaults,space_cache,compress,subvol=@home 0       2
```

Anyway don't handling the mount options of COW and compression.

```
$ mount |grep btrfs

/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=zlib:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=474,subvol=/@)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=zlib:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@home)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /boot type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=zlib:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=482,subvol=/@boot)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/vm type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodatasum,nodatacow,space_cache,subvolid=1534,subvol=/@vm)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/downloads type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodatasum,nodatacow,space_cache,subvolid=1535,subvol=/@downloads)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/sda3 type btrfs (rw,relatime,nodatasum,nodatacow,space_cache,subvolid=259,subvol=/@)
```

Another manual mount:

```
$ sudo btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@vm
$ sudo mount -o subvol=/@/mnt/@vm,nodatacow,compress=no,ssd,noatime /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/vm

$ mount |grep @vm
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /mnt/vm type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zlib:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=503,subvol=/@/mnt/@vm)
```

Look like some options are inherited.

I tryed it when loaded from ssd and from hhd.